# bad quality after rescaling/resizing bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, resize

i'm having Quality issue after rescaling bitmap
i load The images from assets so decoding them have to done by Stream

here is my method

```
  InputStream is = getAssets().open(lol.get(zpositions));   
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
  Bitmap mBitmap    = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,width,hight, false);
```

i tried

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
options.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;

Bitmap bitmapsrc = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
Bitmap mBitmap  = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapsrc,width,hight, false);
```

but still same issue

any idea how to bypass this issue? thanks

here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="1dip"
android:background="@android:color/black" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   />
```

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fullimage);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
       width = display.getWidth();  
       height = display.getHeight(); 

       AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

     Intent i = getIntent();
    List<String> lol = i.getStringArrayListExtra("lol");
    this.lol = lol;
     pagerPosition = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

 {

 public Bitmap getbitBitmap() throws IOException{
    positions = MyPageChangeListener.getCurrentPage();


    if (positions == 0) {
         zpositions = pagerPosition;

    }
    InputStream is = getAssets().open(lol.get(zpositions)); 
            Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inScaled = false;

    Bitmap bitmapsrc = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);


    return bitmapsrc;

}

          private void CropWallpaper() throws IOException {
      Bitmap mBitmap    = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapsrc,width, height, false);    
        try {
            setWallpaper(mBitmap);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Cropped successfully" ,      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Failed to Crop" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to increase the size, or decrease? Increasing will inherently have negative effects on quality. Decreasing will also, to some extent, but these can normally be solved by playing with aliasing.

Comment: We need to know the width and height of the resource image in your "assets" folder AND the width and height that you are sending to `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`.

Comment: Have you checked these?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041207/android-quality-of-the-images-resized-in-runtime
  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231817/quality-problems-when-resizing-an-image-at-runtime?rq=1

Comment: i'm trying to resize the image to fit the screen size i know the bitmap width/height also screen width/size but using Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() decrease the quality after resizing that's my problem

Answer (score 0):

Image quality is always visibly degraded to some amount when increasing the size of an image. Therefore, the resolution of your resource image in your "assets" folder is smaller than the screen on which you are displaying it when you scale the image to "fit the screen size".

The solution is to use an image at least the size of the largest screen on which you plan to display it. You can do this in two ways:

1. Find the original source of the image that is now in your "assets"
   folder and resize it to the size of a relatively large android
   device screen, such as 1280x800. Don't go much larger, because you
   will get an `OutOfMemoryError` when you attempt to open the image.
2. If your image is already small and you don't have access to a larger
   original copy, then I suggest resizing it in Photoshop or with
   another desktop imaging product before putting into your "assets"
   folder. These imaging products will do a better job of uprezing your image
   than the Android OS can do in real-time.

Finally, if you experience an `OutOfMemoryError`, your options will be to either:

1. Reduce the size of your image until you find an acceptable balance
   between size and display quality, or
2. Move your image from the "assets" folder into several different size images in 
    the standard
   "drawable-hdpi", "drawable-mdpi", etc. directory structure.
   The OS will open an image in one of these directories which is in 
   accordance with screen density that 
   is more likely to be proportional to the Heap Memory capabilities of 
   the hardware.

Of course, you can also use `BitmapFactory.Options` such as 32 bit (`ARGB444`) and dither when up-scaling, but this will only help so much when increasing the size of your image for display.

Comment: well i'm using HD Quality and still bad quality and i'm using memory/disk cashe so outofmemoryerror is rare

Comment: but how i can use bitmapfactory options with stream decode and then rescaling ?

Comment: Sidetrack for a moment, but this is probably more important than `BitmapFactory.Options`. I don't think you should scale your `Bitmap` at all in your app. Once any `Bitmap` is open, use your layout to control the display scaling (i.e. XML `android:layout_width="match_parent"`). You may also have to use `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` or similar. So, go back to the beginning, open your image from the `InputStream` and display it as per this comment. You may also want to use `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`.

Comment: i want to scale images so i can set it as wallpaper i don't think that will work with setting wallpaper

Comment: You're welcome. You can set `RGB_8888` in your options before this: `Bitmap bitmapsrc = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);`. But, your best improvement will be to put larger images in your "assets" as recommended in the answer.

Comment: i did exactly that but after rescaling bitmapsrc  image quality turns so bad

Comment: Here is a repost of a question I asked you 23 hours ago. It is time to provide the answers: _"We need to know the width and height of the resource image in your "assets" folder AND the width and height that you are sending to Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()."_

Comment: Please also show the layout XML for display of the image. Edit your question.

Comment: Try `getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tried all combinations of `BitmapOptions`, try setting the filter parameter when creating the scaled bitmap.

```
Bitmap mBitmap  = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapsrc,width,hight, true);
```

It smooths out the images when up-scaled.